# Mount remote FTP folder to local directory

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Lubuntu 12.04 and need either a GUI or command line way to create a folder on my desktop that will actually be connected to a remote FTP folder.  I've scoured the web for tutorials but any Ubuntu tutorials rely on GUI tools that I don't seem to have.  Can someone offer tips for doing this either by the command line or by a *Lubuntu* tool variant?  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this is worth a read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not have been this difficult:

```
mkdir SomeLocalFolder

sshfs login@YourRemoteSite: ~/SomeLocalFolder
```

Done.  Thanks to @TeTeT for the wikipedia tip, which led (indirectly) to the syntax I needed.  Whew!  Wasn't hard, but without the right keywords to search for or knowing already that sshfs was the tool I was looking for, it was really hard to Google the right answer.

Anyway...this is what I was looking for!